# setting a page as "posts page" ignores attributes like page template in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've selected a specific page in wordpress to display posts. I also set a custom page template to be used for this page, but is ignored. 
The page is displayed using the default template.

I have no idea how to solve it, suppose it's a wordpress bug or something. Using the latest Wordpress.
Thank you

Comment: what is your theme structure? you can have templates either inside a folder or file names starting with template-** which template does it use? index, page or single?

Comment: I have templates inside a subfolder. Other pages work correctly.

Comment: So im guessing the loop is correct? also what do you see if you use `get_page_template`?

Comment: I'm getting ..../blog/wp-content/themes/vibetracetheme/page.php. I've read on some sites and they said it's default behaviour to get index.php template.

Answer (score 0):

That's the default behaviour I believe.

Wordpress' template for the posts page will be index.php or home.php.

You have 2 options :

You could copy the page template file and call it home.php and make sure it includes the default loop in the markup.

**or**

Add in a custom loop on that particular template page (read more on inserting a loop here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)